# React - Why Props do not update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal

I just noticed that the props I send for my PayPal Sandbox are not updated.

### Context:

I have an add cart page where the user can increase / decrease the quantity of a product they have in their cart.

I also display the total amount of the cart.

These two values: Quantity and Total are sent by props to the PayPal component (A button).

Except that if the user changes the quantity, these new values are not taken into account by my PayPal button. So I have to manually refresh the page. Which is a huge problem.

Here is my code:

```js
export default function PanierPage() {

    let MonTotal = '';

    const classPanier = PanierStyles();

        const [total, setTotal] = useState([])
        
        // Récupération des détails des paniers
        const [paniers, setPaniers] = useState([])
        const getPaniersDetails = () => [
            getDetails(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('User')).id).then(response => {
                setPaniers(response.data)
            }).catch(err => console.log(err))
        ]

        const handleIncrement = (id, quantite) => {
                updateQuantite(id, quantite + 1 ).then(response => {
                    getDetails(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('User')).id).then(response => {
                        setPaniers(response.data)
                    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
                    getTotal(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('User')).id).then(response => {
                        setTotal(response.data)
                    }).catch(err => console.log(err)) 
            }).catch(err => console.log(err))
        }
        
        const handleDecrement = (id, quantite) => {
            updateQuantite(id, quantite - 1 ).then(response => {
                getDetails(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('User')).id).then(response => {
                    setPaniers(response.data)
                }).catch(err => console.log(err))
                getTotal(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('User')).id).then(response => {
                    setTotal(response.data)
                }).catch(err => console.log(err))
            }).catch(err => console.log(err))
        }

        const SupprPanier = (id) => {
            deletePanier(id).then(response => {
                getDetails(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('User')).id).then(response => {
                    setPaniers(response.data)
                }).catch(err => console.log(err))
                getTotal(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('User')).id).then(response => {
                    setTotal(response.data)
                }).catch(err => console.log(err))
            }).catch(err => console.log(err))
        }


        // Affichage des détails des paniers 
        const paniersAffichage = paniers.map((panier) => (
            <Grid container style={{justifyContent:'center', padding: '1em'}}>
                <Card key={panier.PAN_ID} style={{height: '100%', display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row'}} variant='outlined'>

                    <CardHeader title={panier.PRO_NOM}/>

                        <CardMedia style={{height: 150, width: 150, marginLeft: 'auto', marginRight: 'auto'}} image={`http://localhost:8090/${panier.PRO_URL}`}/>

                        <Grid direction="row" justify="center" alignItems="center">
                            <CardContent>
                                {panier.PAN_QUANTITE === panier.PRO_QTESTOCK
                                ?
                                    <Button variant='outlined' color="primary" disabled onClick={() => handleIncrement(panier.PAN_ID, panier.PAN_QUANTITE)}> + </Button>
                                :
                                    <Button variant='outlined' color="primary" onClick={() => handleIncrement(panier.PAN_ID, panier.PAN_QUANTITE)}> + </Button>
                                }
                                <Typography style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                                    {panier.PAN_QUANTITE}
                                </Typography>

                                {panier.PAN_QUANTITE === 1 
                                ?
                                    <Button variant='outlined' color="secondary" disabled onClick={() => handleDecrement(panier.PAN_ID, panier.PAN_QUANTITE)}> - </Button>
                                :
                                    <Button variant='outlined' color="secondary" onClick={() => handleDecrement(panier.PAN_ID, panier.PAN_QUANTITE)}> - </Button>
                                }
                            </CardContent>
                        </Grid>
                        <Box>
                            <Grid container direction="row" justify="center" alignItems="center" >
                                <Typography style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                                    {panier.PRO_PRIX} €
                                </Typography>
                                <CardActions>
                                    <Button onClick={() => SupprPanier(panier.PAN_ID)} className={classPanier.iconDelete}><DeleteIcon/></Button>
                                </CardActions>
                            </Grid>
                        </Box>
                </Card>
            </Grid>
        ));
        
        
        const PanierTotal = () => {
            getTotal(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('User')).id).then(response => {
                setTotal(response.data)
            }).catch(err => console.log(err))
        }

        const TotalAffiche = total.map((total) => (
            <Grid style={{color: 'white', marginTop: '2%', marginBottom: '2%',}}>
                Montant total de votre panier : {total.TOTAL} €
            </Grid>
        ))

        // Chargement des produits
        useEffect(() => {
            getPaniersDetails();
            PanierTotal();
        }, [])

    return (
            <>
                {paniersAffichage}
                <Grid container style={{justifyContent:'center'}}>
                {TotalAffiche}
                <Grid style={{marginLeft: '2%'}}>
                    {(total.length > 0 && paniers.length > 0) && <PayPal prixTotal={total[0].TOTAL} paniers={paniers} />}
                </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </>
        );
}
```

And my PayPal button :

```js
export default function Paypal({prixTotal, paniers}) 
{
    
    const PDFGeneration = () => {
        var doc = new jsPDF('p','px','a4','false');
        var lesPaniers = paniers.map(panier => [panier.PRO_NOM, panier.PAN_QUANTITE, panier.PRO_PRIX ]);

        doc.text(10,15,'Résumé de votre commande : ');
        doc.autoTable({
            theme: 'grid',
            startY: 20,
            head: [['Nom', 'Quantité', 'Prix (€)']],
            body: lesPaniers,
        });
        doc.text(10,120,`Total de la commande : ${prixTotal} €`);
        doc.text(10,150,'A la prochaine fois !');
        doc.save('CommandeInfo.pdf');
    }

    const paypal = useRef()

    useEffect(() => {

        window.paypal.Buttons({
            style: {
                color: 'gold',
            },
            createOrder: (data, actions) => {
                return actions.order.create({
                    intent: 'CAPTURE',
                    purchase_units: [
                        {
                            description: 'Transaction du site E-Commerce.',
                            amount: {
                                currency_code: 'EUR',
                                value: prixTotal
                            }
                        }]
                })
            },
            onApprove: (data, actions) => {
                createCommande(true).then(response => {
                    PDFGeneration();
                    window.location.reload(false);
                });
                return actions.order.capture();
            },
            onCancel: (data, actions) => {
                console.log("Transaction annulé");
                console.log(prixTotal)
            }
        }).render(paypal.current)
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <div ref={paypal}></div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

However, each product in the shopping cart is assigned a key that NORMALLY should trigger a re-render of the values for PayPal.

If anyone can explain/find me the problem, I would be grateful! Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 1):

In your PayPal component you do not pass any list to the useEffect hook as a second argument. That way it will be executed only when the component is mounted. If you want to update it when the props change you should pass the props that need to trigger it as a second argument list:

```
export default function Paypal({prixTotal, paniers}) 
{
    // ...
    useEffect(() => {
        if (window.paypalBtn) window.paypalBtn.close();
        window.paypalBtn = window.paypal.Buttons({
            // ...
        });
        window.paypalBtn.render(paypal.current)
    }, [prixTotal, paniers]);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work as planned.
With your method, every time the user changes the value a new "PayPal" button now appears on my page. Indeed this new button contains the new values but ... I don't really want to have a new button every time I change a value ^^

Comment: Well in this case you will need to change your logic how you add a button. Maybe remove the old one and show the new one?

Comment: I don't think having "multiple button" is a good idea. And my button logic is pretty simple : {(total.length > 0 && paniers.length > 0) && <PayPal prixTotal={total[0].TOTAL} paniers={paniers} />}. There must be another way.

Comment: No I mean the logic in the useEffect. I updated my answer. Try to store and close() the button if it is already rendered and then show the new one.

Comment: Okay it's working now, even if you can clearly see that the button disappears and reappear... Well, it's one way to do it ! Thanks you for your answer !